# Object as an instance variable in Singleton Class Java

Tags: java, android, object, singleton

I want to maintain single instance of MyModel Class throughout my application. So i have created a Singleton class which looks  like:

```
public class MySingleton {

    private MySingleton () {}

    public MyModel getMyModel() {
        return myModel;;
    }

    public void setEmotionRecord(EmotionRecord emotionRecord) {
        this.emotionRecord = emotionRecord;
    }

    private static MySingleton instance;

    private MyModel myModel = new MyModel();


    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {

            instance = new MySingleton ();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Where MyModel is a model class, which looks something like:

```
 public class MyModel {
    int a;
    String b;
    private MyModel() {}
//....Getter Setter of a and b
}
```

Can i consider it as a good Singleton class?

Comment: Yes, it is a singleton. Do you really need 2 classes? Why you don't create MyModel as singleton?

Comment: Yes i do need two classes, as sometimes i need to have several instances of MyModel class in my app. Well thanks :)

Comment: Singleton means you can have only one instance of class.

Comment: That's perfectly clear to me. But given a scenario in which i need the same  model class for any other operation then i will have to create two classes for that i.e. one Singleton and another is normal model class having same data as the Singleton one. So to prevent that i have created the Singleton like that.